# remove a value with its counterpart conditional on an ID

Tags: r, remove-if

I have the following data frame

| neto | damo |
| --- | --- |
| 356 | 008 |
| -356 | 008 |
| -175 | 009 |
| 700 | 009 |
| -700 | 009 |
| 250 | 009 |
| -36 | 018 |
| -36 | 018 |
| -36 | 018 |

I want to eliminate the data with its counterpart conditioned to the ID and that it looks like this:

| neto | damo |
| --- | --- |
| -175 | 009 |
| 250 | 009 |
| -108 | 018 |

I have tried to put it in absolute values and leave the value that is unique, but this can produce an error if both are negative and should not be eliminated.

Comment: ? I do not understand. Could you please clarify?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: por ejemplo debe eliminarse los que son iguales en el id y tienen contraparte: 
 ID        Neto    
1         -34
1          34
1        - 8
1        - 8

debe quedar 
ID        neto
1         -8
1          -8

Answer (score 0):

```
df %>%
  mutate(abs_neto=abs(neto)) %>%
  group_by(damo,abs_neto) %>%
  mutate(one_plus_one_minus= any(neto>=0) & any(neto<=0))%>%
  filter(n()==1 | !one_plus_one_minus)%>%
  ungroup 

   neto  damo abs_neto one_plus_one_minus
  <int> <int>    <int> <lgl>             
1  -175     9      175 FALSE             
2   250     9      250 FALSE             
3   250     9      250 FALSE
```

Answer (score 0):

We may group by 'damo', remove the groups having only a single absolute 'neto' value, grouped by `abs`olute of 'neto', filter out the groups having one value

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   mutate(s1 = sign(neto), absneto = abs(neto)) %>% 
   arrange(damo, desc(absneto), s1 == -1) %>% 
   group_by(damo) %>% 
   mutate(grp = cumsum(s1 > 0)) %>% 
   group_by(grp, .add = TRUE) %>% 
   filter(n_distinct(absneto) > 1|n_distinct(s1) == 1) %>% 
   group_by(s1, .add = TRUE) %>% 
   summarise(neto = sum(neto), .groups = "drop") %>%   
   select(-grp, -s1)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 × 2
   damo  neto
  <int> <int>
1     9  -175
2     9   250
3    18  -108
```

#### data

```
df1 <-structure(list(neto = c(356L, -356L, -175L, 700L, -700L, 250L, 
-36L, -36L, -36L), damo = c(8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 18L, 18L, 
18L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

Comment: I like your idea, but what would I do in the case where there was no positive value, only negative, and they had to be accumulated? I add it to the question
thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @BelkyXiomaraMayorgaArdila try the updated solution